# Cloudwatch - remove log delay

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to debug some issues on our Java server, but the cloudwatch logs are about 15 minutes delayed for everything (then outputs a batch of logs), is there a way to remove this or somehow monitor the logs directly? I'm very new to cloudwatch / aws in general.